# Display sliders only on mobile device not desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, media-queries

How to modify DOM on the fly by replacing the existing HTML code based on device width. Used @media queries to hide or show the content, tried Jquery resize function using **.after** method to modify it. Need Help

**DEMO** [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/euQ5n/268/)

**Used code**

```
function resizefunction(){
 if ($(window).width() < 500)
 {
   var $leftsec = $(".active li:nth-child(4)").html();
   var $rightsec = $(".active li:nth-child(5)").html();
   $( ".active" ).after( "<li>" + $leftsec+ "</li><li>" + $rightsec+ "</li>" );
   $(".active div:nth-child(4)").css("display","none");
   $(".active div:nth-child(5)").css("display","none");
 }
 else
 {
   console.log('Resize > 500');
 }
};
```

**Desktop Version**

```
<html>
 <body>
 <ul class="parent">
  <li class="active">1st slider
  <ul class="child">
   <li>1</li>
   <li>2</li>
   <li>3</li>
   <li>4</li>
 </ul>
 </li>
  <li>2st slider
   <ul class="child">
    <li>1</li>
    <li>2</li>
    <li>3</li>
    <li>4</li>
  </ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image: Desktop Version showing 4 boxes]

**Mobile Version**

```
<html>
 <body>
  <ul class="parent">
   <li class="active">1st slider
    <ul class="child">
     <li>1</li>
     <li>2</li>
    </ul>
   </li>
   <li>2st slider
     <ul class="child">
      <li>3</li>
      <li>4</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </body>
</html>
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: can you provide a working code

Comment: LINK [ http://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/euQ5n/268/ ] Demo Open Console to see the changes of display none in the class {.current}

Answer (score 0):

Are you by chance looking to know about the function $(window).resize()? Ref:- https://api.jquery.com/resize/

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  // This will execute whenever the window is resized
  $(window).width(); // New width
});
```

Reference for above code:- http://www.sweet-web-design.com/wordpress/detecting-browser-window-size-resize-with-jquery/1614/

Comment: Resize will work based on width, how to iterate on a slider ?

Comment: Do you want to write codes for the dom manipulation or do you want to write when to execute dom manipulation?

Comment: @SuryaRPraveen Here's a link to pure css slider - http://cssslider.com/wordpress-slideshow-32.html

After that what you can do is create two doms, one for mobile and the other for desktop and manipulate the way you want to. :)

Comment: DOM Manipulation to slide presentations optimized for Mobile Phones and Tablets

Comment: @SuryaRPraveen  Please check the comments. I have posted what you require. However in case you need it optimized and all, then I won't be able to help as I do not have any experience in it.

Comment: DEMO - http://jsfiddle.net/ssuryar/euQ5n/268/ - No access to create two DOMs. Can only be able to modify LIVE.

Comment: You can create functions which toggle between creating doms for the desktop and mobile view since it is the script that you require.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142914/discussion-between-surya-r-praveen-and-sagar).